# Add specific lines to text file

Tags: python, text

I have a long text file and I want to do the following...
Here is part of my text file:

[image]

and this is what I want it to look like after running the code:

[image]

Can anyone suggest any code for this in python?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic way to do something like this, check out the docs on reading and writing files in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Also, learn about list comprehension: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Using that, here's an easy-to-understand approach you could take.

1. After opening a file, read all the non-blank lines (`line.strip()` returns a string with any leading or trailing blank space removed, and an empty string returns false).

   ```
   # add every stripped line in the file if it's not empty
   lines = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]
   ```
2. Make a new list and copy data over with the new stuff.

   ```
   newlines = []
   # go from start to end of list, increment by 2
   for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
     # add the first part
     newlines.append("signed char...")
     # add the two parts from the original file
     newlines.extend(lines[i:i+2])
     # add the last part
     newlines.append("};")
   ```
3. Write `newlines` to a file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but if you look closely you see that in my target I change the names like wc11,wc12,wc13 and so on... how can I do that? In your example I can add wc11 for example in all of the specific lines... Can you help me on this as well? I really appreciate your help by the way, you really saved me lot of time

Comment: Outside of the for loop, make a variable to keep track of the number, and increment it by one at the end of the body of the loop. No worries, but for future reference, I do recommend you dive deeper into Python basics and make an attempt before posting a question. It'll save you some question-asking time and the time of people answering.

Comment: Yeah I know what you are talking about... as a digital electronic student I have little to no experience in python. anyway... thank you so much you really helped me big time...